# When I have maven clean the project, it reminder Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have never meet the ERROR, before last night.

```
[ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar must specify an absolute path but is ${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar @ com.vipkid.ycb:fin-ycb-schedule:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT, /Users/xuyang/vipkid/fin-ycb-schedule/pom.xml, line 57, column 25
```

The pom file is red below

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
```

and I reset the maven is not working, 
[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgTVr.png)

Comment: My first question is what has changed between when you did not see the error and when you did see the error. I assume `${JAVA_HOME}` is an environment variable that must be set. My first impression is that the error indicates it is not. Or the environment variable is set but for some reason when trying to access the jar file the environment variable being used in the path is not being expanded properly so instead of the environment variable being used to replace `${JAVA_HOME}` the application doesn't do a replacement but just tries to use the path as is. May need to do manual replacement.

Comment: Show us what `/Users/xuyang/vipkid/fin-ycb-schedule/pom.xml` contains.  Put it into the question.

Comment: 1)Check your environment variable for JAVA_HOME. It looks like it's wrong. 2) Try delete the systemPath line in the POM

Comment: Thank you very much, It works, because the pom fragment does not need.

Comment: Why do you need the tools.jar file? What kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I don't need the **tools.jar**, My partner adds it on git, and I pull it, I'm new to Java, and I use **IDEA**, he uses **Eclipse**, he needs it to assign maven to java LoginServlet.  I'm not sure didn't I need it, so when it reports an error, I just want to solve, the fact is that I didn't need it.